# how can get the mutual friend of google plus in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, addressbook, google-plus

I am using the developer Google   https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth.
I want to get the mutual/common friend in api.
Can it is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the current REST APIs for Google+.

If you'd like to learn more about what is available, you can check out the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/). If it's an API that you need, you can also request it using the [platform issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry).